# Using "href" in Javascript View with VBox-SAP UI5

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

I am trying to navigate to other pages from my SAP UI-5 App.  (HTML's `< a href />` )

I used `sap.m.Link` on my Toolbar to navigate to other pages , and it worked perfectly ;

```
new sap.m.Link(this.createId("Foo"),{ 
                text: "Foo",
                type: "Transparent",
                href: myLink
            }).addStyleClass("headerLink"),
```

However I am using  `VBox` in a `customTile` where I have a text. I want to implement same functionality  to my `VBox` aswell . How can I do it ?

Please note  I can't use  `window.location.replace("http://mywebsite.com/nextPage.html");`  because It disallows me to return back to last page I visited.

My `customTile` looks like this

```
var iconBox1 = new sap.m.VBox({
        items: [
            new sap.m.HBox({
                items: [
                    new sap.m.Text({
                        text: "Foo" // I want to navigate after clicking on this Text or this Box generelly
                    }).addStyleClass("tileTextDashboard")
                ]
            }).addStyleClass("textNumberConatainer")
        ]
    });


var customTile1 = new sap.m.CustomTile(this.createId("tile1"), {
            content: [
                iconBox1
            ],
            press: [oController.someFunction, oController]
}).addStyleClass("customTileDashboard");
```

Comment: If you found a solution then add it as such in an answer and not your question. That is the idea of answers ;) After 2 days you can accept your own answer as well. Please don't answer in the question because that is not what it should be used for :)

Comment: Oh thanks, I will change it later and add as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT : Problem solved !

In case someone has same problem, I am adding my solution :

```
var myLink= "https://foo.com";
var myLinkO= new sap.m.Link({
        text: "text foo",
        type: "Transparent",
        href: myLink
    }).addStyleClass("classFoo");
```

and now you only need to replace myLinkO  in your `items` array in your `VBox`